# Angularjs jQuery bxslider is not affecting content of partial view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, partial-views, bxslider

I'm building Angular application and I have problem with bxSlider. I know that I can't use js inside partial view. So I moved it to main page but code is not applied on rendered partial.

Is there any way ho to trigger this javascript after partial renders? Like put this javascript inside element and trigger it from controller when partial is loaded?